# SonarQube Sonar - Project File Bubble Chart

Tags: file, plugins, sonarqube, bubble-chart

I have latest SonarQube and it's plugin for "Project File Bubble Chart".

Everything is working fine. On the dash, I see valid information for every good plugin I installed.

The newly added "Project File Bubble Chart" plugin - seems like has some bug or may be its the browser. Any time I use my mouse's left button, I notice that the box for Bubble chart boundary gets expanded by few centimeters per each mouse click. Sometimes, if you refresh the page, everything is back to normal for this plugin, but again this time you might even see it getting expanded by just moving your mouse here n there on the screen or using mouse roller (middle button).

Are you seeing this shenzi as well?

---

FireFox doesn't have this behavior/issue.

Comment: What's your browser, OS, ...?

Comment: IE, Win7, It's a browser issue. I just installed FF and checked and this issue doesn't exist in FF.

Comment: Indeed, see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements

Comment: IE version that Im using is 9.0.x which this above posts says it's supported. Anyways, it's a browser issue so I can live with FF and will try IE if I upgrade it to another version. Thanks a lot Dave.